# Assigning border attribute to button

Tags: android, xml

I have 4 buttons with across an horizontally-orientated linearlayout which are evenly weighted to split them over a the width of the screen but to improve the appearance, and clearly define the outlines of the buttons, I want to set borders to the buttons but can't figure out how! (I know, this is pathetic!)

I've looked around and can't find the answer - Points for grabs!
Here's the attributes for the button:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dot"
        android:id="@+id/dot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@color/Button_Color"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="SelectDot"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to add border to the buttons you can create custom drawable and set border attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to space out your buttons, add a layout_margin attribute inside your button definition, such as:

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```

If you want an actual stroke line around the edge of the button, here is a quick way to create it: http://angrytools.com/android/button/

Just design what you want in there and copy the xml to your file.

Comment: Great link - Thanks!